# Simple hello world aseembly program prints out trash

Tags: linux, assembly

I am using a x86 assembly to make a simple program that compares two words and prints out if they are equal (i know its usless im just learning and testing out things) its working properly but right after the answer i get printed out with alot of garbage and i dont understand what is causing this bug

```
    SECTION .bss
    SECTION .text
    SECTION .data
    HelloMsg: db "Helllo",10
    HelloLength: equ $-HelloMsg

    HellloMsg: db "Helllo",10
    HellloLength: equ $-HellloMsg

    One: db "First",10
    OneLen: equ $-One

    Two: db "Second",10
    TwoLen: equ $-Two

    global _start

    _start:
    nop
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,HellloLength
    mov edx,HelloLength

    cmp ecx,edx
    je true
    mov ecx,One
    mov edx,OneLen
    int 80H

    true:
    mov ecx,Two 
    mov edx,One
    int 80H

    MOV eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80H
```

Output :

[image]

Sorry if im asking a stupid question or if my program is hard to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small bug in the code. When calling the write system call `edx` must contain the length of the string to be written. However, in the case that the comparison strings have the same length (the `true:` case), your code is:

```
true:
mov ecx,Two
mov edx,One
int 80H
```

but `One` refers to the string "First", not the length of string `Two`.

Fix it by changing it to:

```
true:
mov ecx,Two
mov edx,TwoLen
int 80H
```